# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n z^{2n}$ using limit conditions

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, functions, power-series

I have a general series defined in the form,
\begin{equation} \tag{1}
\Lambda(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n z^{2n}
\end{equation}
I have to impose two limiting values for this according to the following, such that RHS of eq. (1) follows,
\begin{equation}
\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\Lambda(z)\rightarrow z^2 \tag{2a}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty}\Lambda(z)\rightarrow 1 \tag{2b}
\end{equation}
The condition (2a) simply sets the value of $c_1$ to be 1. 
Satisfying both the conditions (2a) and (2b) is more non-trivial and has a number of solutions. Some examples include
$$
c_n = (-1)^{n-1} \qquad \Lambda(z)=\frac{z^2}{1+z^2} \\
c_n = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n!} \qquad \Lambda(z)=1 - e^{-z^2} \\
c_n = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n+1)!} \qquad \Lambda(z)= \left[1 - \frac{\sin\left(z\right)}{z} \right] \\
$$

EDIT 2: Few more cases
$$
c_n = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n+1} \qquad \Lambda(z) = 1 - \frac{\ln\left[1+z^2\right]}{z^2} \\
c_n = \frac{E_{2n}}{(2n)!} \qquad \Lambda(z) = 1 - \mathrm{sech}\left(z\right)
$$

Here $E_n$ is the Euler number, defined according to [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerNumber.html)

**Is it possible to find general recursion formula to generate $c_n$ that will satisfy both the conditions (2a) and (2b) and provide a convergent series for eq. (1)?**

EDIT 1: Trial by differentiation

differentiating eqs (2a) and (2b)

\begin{equation}
\lim_{z  \rightarrow 0}\frac{d\Lambda}{dz}\rightarrow 2z \\
\lim_{z  \rightarrow 0}\frac{d^2\Lambda}{dz^2}\rightarrow 2 
\tag{3a}
\end{equation}

Can we somehow reconstruct the differential equation of $\Lambda_h(z)$ that will satisfy these conditions? Then this can generate a family of such functions.

Comment: What do you mean by letting $kx_0 \to 0$ and $kx_0 \to \infty$? Specifically, how each of $k$ and $x_0$ should vary?

Comment: @SangchulLee There are no specific constraints on $k$ and $x_0$.

Comment: So I guess that you are actually reparametrizing $\Lambda$ as a function of $z=kx_0$ and $x_0$, $$\Lambda(z,x_0)=x_0^2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n z^{2n-2},$$ and then studying its limit as either $z\to0$ or $z\to\infty$. Then I am not sure how each of your three examples, $$\frac{x_0^2}{1+z^2}, \qquad x_0^2 \frac{1-e^{-z^2}}{z^2}, \qquad \frac{x_0^2}{z^2} \left[ 1-\frac{\sin z}{z}\right], $$ satisfies the second condition $\Lambda(z,x_0)\to1$ as $z\to\infty$. (To me, it seems that $\Lambda(z,x_0)\to0$ as $z\to\infty$ in all three cases.)

Comment: @SangchulLee I am sorry for the confusion. I made a mistake when I had defined the original functions $\Lambda(k)$, I have rectified them now. Please check